# Get a type identified by a string in the Scala macros

Tags: scala, macros

I have a bunch of strings (essentially names of `java.lang.` classes and some custom classes). In the macro I need to add the type to the function:

```
q"""propKey[${resolveType(c)(argType)}]($name, classOf[$argType])"""
```

where `argType` is `String`.

So far I tried `q"$argType"` - but that adds the weird signature `propKey[String("java.lang.Integer")](...)`

with `c.universe.TypeName`- there's no method to get a `c.universe.Type` instance.

Comment: `c.mirror.staticClass("java.lang.String").toType`

Comment: @余杰水 pls post as an answer, so I can accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c.mirror.staticClass("java.lang.String").toType`

Comment: Please try to explain your code a bit for a more complete answer.